# How do I print certain parts of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def option_A():
 print("Pick a Fixture!")
 fixture_choice = int(input("Enter: "))

 file = open("firesideFixtures.txt", "r")
 fixture_number = file.readlines(fixture_choice)
 fixture = [linecache.getline("firesideFixtures.txt", fixture_choice)] 
 print(fixture)
 file.close()
```

The first line from the file I am using is:

```
1,02/09/15,18:00,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc
```

The expected result is:

```
1, 02/09/15, RNGesus, Ingsoc, Y, Ingsoc
```

The result I get:

```
['1,02/09/15,18:00,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc\n']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the only element of your list by indexing into it:

```
print(fixture[0])
```

Output:

```
1,02/09/15,18:00,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc
```

Or, even better don't create a list in the fist place (note the missing `[]`):

```
fixture = linecache.getline("firesideFixtures.txt", fixture_choice)
```

> How can I remove the "18:00" part from the output because all I need is "1,02/09/15, RNGesus, Ingsoc, Y, Ingsoc" (from comment)

Now, remove the time:

```
fixture = linecache.getline("firesideFixtures.txt", fixture_choice) 
parts = fixture.split(',')
res = ','.join(parts[:2] + parts[3:])
print(res)
print(fixture)
```

Output:

```
1,02/09/15,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc
```

Comment: Or just remove [ ] from line fixture = [linecache.getline("firesideFixtures.txt", fixture_choice)]

Comment: Yes. Just saw this.

Comment: How can I remove the "18:00" part from the output because all I need is "1,02/09/15, RNGesus, Ingsoc, Y, Ingsoc"